# How to make lengthy downloads in golang

Tags: go

how to make lengthy downloads in golang
which means downloading a zip file using url which has almost 15GB data.

In my case download is not successful and the call is crashing after running for so long.
Downloading large files, such as a 15GB zip file, in Golang involves managing the download process efficiently to avoid crashes and handle potential issues like timeouts or connection errors. how to resolve them

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "net/http"
    "os"
    "path/filepath"
)

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/download", downloadHandler)
    port := 8080
    fmt.Printf("Server is listening on :%d...\n", port)
    err := http.ListenAndServe(fmt.Sprintf(":%d", port), nil)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error starting server:", err)
    }
}

func downloadHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fileURL := "https://example.com/largefile.zip" // Replace with your actual file URL
    fileName := "largefile.zip"
    downloadPath := "./downloads/" + fileName // Adjust the download path as needed

    err := downloadFile(fileURL, downloadPath)
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, fmt.Sprintf("Failed to download file: %v", err), http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }

    w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
    w.Write([]byte("File downloaded successfully"))
}

func downloadFile(url string, filepath string) error {
    response, err := http.Get(url)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer response.Body.Close()

    if response.StatusCode != http.StatusOK {
        return fmt.Errorf("unexpected status code: %d", response.StatusCode)
    }

    // Create the file
    out, err := os.Create(filepath)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer out.Close()

    // Create a progress writer to track the download progress
    progress := &progressWriter{writer: out}

    // Copy the response body to the file, and track the progress
    _, err = io.Copy(progress, response.Body)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    return nil
}

type progressWriter struct {
    writer    io.Writer
    total     int64
    downloaded int64
}

func (pw *progressWriter) Write(p []byte) (int, error) {
    n, err := pw.writer.Write(p)
    pw.downloaded += int64(n)
    pw.printProgress()
    return n, err
}

func (pw *progressWriter) printProgress() {
    fmt.Printf("\rDownloading... %.2f%% complete", float64(pw.downloaded)/float64(pw.total)*100)
}
```

Comment: What does "call is crashing after running for so long" mean?

Comment: it returns internal server error 502 @AKX

Comment: An http 502 is not a crash, not is it returned by your code here. You need to explain what exactly isn't working in order for someone to help.

Comment: If the server supports the [Range Header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Range) you may be able to pick up where you left off.